# RabbitMQ NACK messages

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

My experience: in a publish/subscribe scenario, if a subscriber nacks a message, the nacked message is immediately re-queued at the front of the queue and it will be the next message the subscriber gets.

Is there a way to avoid this? Is is possible to nack a message in a way that the next message will definetly not be the one just nacked?

I am using Node.js and [amqp.node](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/) to communicate with RabbitMQ

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Nack` is a RabbitMQ-specific enhancement to the AMQP protocol. It allows a consumer of a message to notify the server when a message **was not** successfully processed.  I assume you got this far already.

The interesting thing here is that AMQP did not originally consider `Nack` to be necessary. Why? Because the AMQP behavior when a consumer is unable to process a message is for the consumer to *close the connection without `ack`-ing the message*. Under this situation, the message is automatically requeued in the order it was originally in, and delivered to the next available consumer with the `redelivered` flag set.

Why would this be?

Because a `Nack` indicates an issue with the consumer, not the message. If the message itself is bad, AMQP assumed that the consumer would be smart enough to recognize this, `ack` the message, then take whatever other steps the programmer designed to deal with bad messages.

RabbitMQ added the `Nack` function which takes a `requeue` parameter. By default, `requeue` is true - meaning upon the nack, the broker will requeue the message. This is in keeping with the original intent of the AMQP design. However, if you pass `requeue` as false, the broker will dead-letter the message. This is a shortcut to the behavior that would normally have been designed in by a smart application architect using AMQP, so you can think of this as a convenience to the programmer.

**Difference Between The Two**

In the first case, the `Nack` indcates a problem with the message consumer. The consumer should take itself offline while it works out its issues.  In the second case, the `Nack` indicates a problem with the message.  The first case is a transient issue, while the second is a permanent failure.

**What if I can't process a particular message *right now* but maybe later?**

If your messaging structure was designed properly, this would never be true. If one particular message requires different processing paths or resources than another message, that message type should have its own queue. Consumers of that queue can stop consuming when a dependency for processing those messages is offline or unavailable.

Comment: "What if I can't process a particular message right now but maybe later? If your messaging structure was designed properly, this would never be true".
You are right: in a properly designed system this would not happen. BUT, legacy code and errors in the past could leave us to deal with these problems today, without being able to fix the design. My scenario is that processing messages could result in concurrent access to DB causing a serialization error due to poor design. Redesigning is unfortunately not an option right now (as much as I would love to), so that's what we have to deal with.

Comment: @smellyarmpits - At some level, your implementation is going to have to account for the original legacy design and fix it. Since I don't know the details, I can't say how you should go about doing that, but at a minimum, you need to have one queue per message type. You don't have to read from the queues concurrently, but you do need to separate out your different types of messages. Beyond that, most databases handle concurrency via locking. This may not be an easy problem to solve!

Comment: > At some level, your implementation is going to have to account for the original legacy design and fix it.

I totally agre, but I am not in charge of these decisions :D

Comment: I really don't know what to tell you then - You've described behavior that is immutable as an issue. If the behavior cannot be changed, and the legacy code cannot be changed, then what can be changed?

Comment: The problem is that the messages are already divided by type on different queues, but different messages may have to work on the same database row, causing concurrency problems (in case of multiple consumers): 2 consumers may pick up 2 different messages that refer to the same db row. If this happens I want to deal with the consumer(s) that failed in order to re queue the message to be processed later, because most likely this kind of error is gonna be solved by delaying the processing

Comment: How long of a delay are we talking about here?  And in all fairness, this is not at all the problem described in the original question :)

Comment: mmm well, the original post is more general and does not describe the problem in detail :)

Comment: Additional precision, `nack` is a RabbitMQ-specific addition which is the same that basic.reject (ie no-ack the message), but allows batching no-acks.

Answer (score 3):

Question: My experience: in a publish/subscribe scenario, if a subscriber nacks a message, the nacked message is immediately re-queued at the front of the queue and it will be the next message the subscriber gets.

> Yes that is correct. When a message is requeued with
>   channel.basicNack, it will be placed to its original position in its
>   queue, if possible. If not (due to concurrent deliveries and
>   acknowledgements from other consumers when multiple consumers share a
>   queue), the message will be requeued to a position closer to queue
>   head. Source: https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html

Question: Is there a way to avoid this? Is is possible to nack a message in a way that the next message will definetly not be the one just nacked?

It is not possible to achieve this with nack. One way to achieve this is by re-publish the message back to queue where ever nack needed.

- Get the message and immediately send the ack back.
- Process the message, if successful do nothing.
- If fails do not send the nack instead republish message back to the
  queue.

Comment: That is a possible solution, but it is subject to a possible data loss if the consumer fails after the ack and before republishing. I guess it could be a possible workaround to republish and then acking, but I don't know if it's a good design or if it would cause noticeable performance issues.

Comment: +1 for the note about republish - while it's probably not what OP is looking for, and won't help if the queue is already empty, it does achieve the relocation of the message to the end of whatever line is there.

Comment: Reordering `try { process message; } finally { if failed then republish; ack message }` -- has the added benefit that an exception in process will still do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you can consider that if your consumer runs normally, you should always ack a message, whatever the result of handling the message (both for errors or success).

You can reject/nack a bad formatted message with requeue = false to route it to a dead letter exchange and have actions on it (bind a queue and consume for e.g. post mortem analysis), or choose to ack it and do whatever is necessary (e.g. send other messages like BadRequest messages, ...).

The best way to (almost) never have problem is to ack as the last action of handling the message, and be prepared to handle redeliveries (idempotency may help). You can ack immediately upon delivery, but if the consumer crashes, the message is lost (and you'll need to handle that case by yourself – there are many patterns for that).

Hope this helps.